# link to pthread library using CMake (in CLion)

Tags: c, cmake, pthreads

I've looked all over and I can't figure out how to get CLion to link the lpthread library. I know that w/ gcc you can just type -lpthread, but I need to do some debugging in CLion.

Here's my current CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(lab4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories(/usr/include/)
link_directories(/usr/include/)

set(SOURCE_FILES lab4_v2.c)
add_executable(lab4 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: This is about CMake, and not about makefile or CLion...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Before CMake 2.8.12:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG)
  set_property(TARGET my_app PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-pthread")
  set_property(TARGET my_app PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-pthread")
endif()
if(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT)
  target_link_libraries(my_app "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")
endif()
```

If you have CMAKE 2.8.12+:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG)
  target_compile_options(my_app PUBLIC "-pthread")
endif()
if(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT)
  target_link_libraries(my_app "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBES_INIT}")
endif()
```

If you have CMake 3.1.0+

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app Threads::Threads)
```

If you want to use one of the first two methods with CMake 3.1+, you will need:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
```

Info taken from [video by Anastasia Kazakova](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1nc9riqksY)

Answer (score 25):

For C:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pthread")
```

Answer (score 21):

you should use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
target_link_libraries(lab4 pthread)
```

Comment: @somecbusnerd : if my answer helped you, consider accepting it.

Comment: Note: might also need to specify `find_package( Threads REQUIRED )` before that (source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40102044/997940)

Answer (score 4):

For C++
use

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -pthread" )
```

Comment: only this one worked for me, not the ones mentioned above

Comment: The same as the previous one.
Can someone explain this please.

Answer (score 3):

Answer as of CLion 2018.2 and the bundled cmake version of 3.12.0

I used other answers in this thread to modify my CMakeLists.txt, and ultimately found I had to add a SECOND line with set() to make this work. My file looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(thread_test_project C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pthread")

include_directories(.)

add_executable(thread_test
        thread_test.c)
```